# Can I Make Password Change Reminders More Obvious

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, password, password-reset

In Windows 7 and Windows 2008 is appears that Microsoft changed how users would be reminded about upcoming password expirations.

In Windows XP the password expiration was very obvious. There was a password change request screen that was displayed after the user logged in asking if they wanted to change their password because it will expire in X number of days.

However in Windows 7/2008 this was changed. Now the user is logged in normally with a small notification bubble that appears for a few seconds in the lower right hand corner of the users screen suggesting that they change their password.

I am looking for a way to go back to the Windows XP type of method, or at least something that is more obvious to the user that they need to change their password. Is there an AD setting, or something else that I can do, to enable the functionality on my users systems?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend providing users notifications via email.

You can do this with software:
http://www.netwrix.com/password_expiration_notifier_freeware.html

Or you can write a script to do it as well.

http://www.sheenaustin.com/2009/06/19/active-directory-password-expiry-reminder-email/

I find a lot of users that are traveling or away from their computer won't realize their password is expiring but with this method they are always notified via email.